# Morris.js chart with PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I need your help for this case.

I have an array in PHP.

How can I apply this array:

```
$visits = $ga->query($params);
```

Witch gave me something like this:

```
Array
(
    [http_code] => 200
    [kind] => analytics#gaData
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20141223
                    [1] => 26
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20141224
                    [1] => 15
                )
...
```

In this code :

```
<? function getVisits() { 
        $morris = new MorrisLineCharts('getVisits');
        $morris->xkey = array('date');
        $morris->ykeys = array('value');
        $morris->labels = array('Money');
        $morris->data = array(
            array('date' => '20141223', 'value' => 26),
            array('date' => '20141224', 'value' => 15),
        );
        echo $morris->toJavascript();
    }
    getVisits();
    ?>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop over the data returned by Google Analytics, to construct an array suitable for Morris.

```
<? function getVisits( $ga_rows = array() ) {

        foreach( $ga_rows as &$_row ) {
             $_row = array('date' => $_row [0], 'value' => $_row [1]);
        }

        $morris = new MorrisLineCharts('getVisits');
        $morris->xkey = array('date');
        $morris->ykeys = array('value');
        $morris->labels = array('Money');
        $morris->data = $ga_rows;
        echo $morris->toJavascript();
    }

    // the relevant data from the array you retreived from Google Analytics
    getVisits( $google_analytics_data['rows'] );
?>
```